# ViewDidAppear() and ViewWillAppear() only called on launch

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin

Likes stated in the title, the ViewDidAppear() and the ViewWillAppear() is only called when the app is launched, and not when it is opened from background, as if they were the ViewDidLoad() method.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? I don't think my code is the problem, but I can post it if you need me to.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you expect those methods to be called again?

Comment: I thought that was the purpose of those methods. What other methods are called when the app appears from background? The ones in AppDelegate isn't to much use since I want to do stuff in my view, and not AppDelegate. Thanks for your quick answer.

Comment: `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` are called when a view controller is being presented.  When an app returns from the background, the view controller has already been presented in the context of your app, so these methods are not called.  If you wish to refresh your views when the app returns from the background then you should observe the `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` `NSNotification`

Answer (score 1):

ViewWillAppear: Creation of UIViews is fairly expensive, and you should avoid as much as possible doing that on the ViewWillAppear method, becuase when this gets called, it means that the iPhone is already ready to show the UIView to the user, and anything heavy you do here will impact performance in a very visible manner (like animations being delayed, etc).

ViewDidAppear: Finally, I use the ViewDidAppear to start off new threads to things that would take a long time to execute, like for example doing a webservice call to get extra data for the form above.The good thing is that because the view already exists and is being displayed to the user, you can show a nice "Waiting" message to the user while you get the data.

If you want to do something when your application comes from background and go in to background do like this
 To get when enter background
In appDelegate.

```
  (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

To get when app comes foreground.

```
(void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```